# LDAP connection bind not successful

Tags: php, apache, ldap

I am trying to make a LDAP connection to a test server from apache2(Ubuntu) with PHP. I have `php-ldap` installed. And this is my connection code snippet.

```
$ldap_dn = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";
$ldap_password = "password";

$ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap.forumsys.com", "389") or die("Not connected");

ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if(ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password)) {

  echo "Bind successful!";

} else {
    echo "Invalid user/pass or other errors!";
}
```

> Log: [:error] [pid 7332] [client 10.9.114.7:47852] PHP Warning: 
>   ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in
>   /var/www/html/connect_test.php

This code works on my localhost. But in the apache2 server, `ldap_connect` is successful but `ldap_bind` is not. Can I know what I am doing wrong? Newbie here! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You need to check the error log and specify in your question what the error actually is.

Comment: Can you pls specify how to check or generate error log?

Comment: You should [read this](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.basics.php) thoroughly. There might be a file called `php_errors.log` available somewhere, or the errors might appear in your apache logs or syslog. It depends on your local PHP config.

Comment: In apache on ubuntu, the log file should be here : `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Thank you @Esteban ! Found the logs! Updated the question! :)

Comment: Does your machine where apache is hosted can connect to the LDAP directory? (Is it reachable on the network?)

Comment: Yes. I use authentication through Active directory which is also LDAP I guess. That works fine. Now I want to connect to this test server which has only LDAP (without active directory). Ref: http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who looks this up later. The problem is - there was a firewall blocking all other LDAP connections except our own. That's the reason why the test LDAP server from forumsys didn't work. Once you install `php-ldap`, you are good to go ahead and connect to any LDAP server if your firewall allows it. Hope this helps! :)